# Correct line-breaking of long math expression

Tags: equations, line-breaking

What is the correct way of breaking such unnumbered equation into multiple lines?

```
\begin{equation*}

\lim_{\bigtriangleup t \to 0^+}\int_{\bigtriangleup t}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\varphi(t_1-\bigtriangleup t,x)-\varphi(t_1,x)}{(-\bigtriangleup t)} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 

=\lim_{\bigtriangleup t \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\varphi(t_1-\bigtriangleup t,x)-\varphi(t_1,x)}{(-\bigtriangleup t)} \chi_{(\bigtriangleup t,T)}(t_1) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 

= \int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t_1} (t_1,x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 .

\end{equation*}
```

It's not an equation actually, I'm proving something in my thesis and I'm just modifying a math expression. So `\multline` is not this case I think. I used `\split` but then it can be aligned to the right side or the left side only because the expressions are too long and it would overfull.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at mathmode with a lot of examples: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thank you, this could be really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tough formula to typeset; there is no "right way", such complex formulas often need specific treatment which depend on their size and also on subtle semantic issues.

Here is my proposal: the initial term is set on a line by itself and the two developments below it with aligned equals, indented to the right.

I changed `\bigtriangleup` into the customary `\Delta`; I also added a definition for the differential symbol that spares you from explicit `\,` commands. Finally I changed the definition of `\phi` to produce `\varphi`, so you can change them all to the "closed" variant by simply commenting the redefinition.

Why `aligned` inside `equation*`? Because this is a single block, so if you decide to number it, you can simply remove the `*`. With `align*` the result would be identical, but numbering it would require more steps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0^+}
& \int_{\Delta t}^{T} \int_{\Omega} 
   D(t_1,x)
   \frac{\phi(t_1-\Delta t,x)-\phi(t_1,x)}{(-\Delta t)}
   \diff x \diff t_1 
\\
&=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0^+} 
  \int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega}
  D(t_1,x) 
  \frac{\phi(t_1-\Delta t,x)-\phi(t_1,x)}{(-\Delta t)}
  \chi_{(\Delta t,T)}(t_1)
  \diff x \diff t_1 
\\
&=\int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega}
  D(t_1,x)
  \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t_1}(t_1,x)
  \diff x \diff t_1 .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's an exhaustive answer, thank you. I will use it.

Comment: +1 for paying such nice close attention to the semantics. If I could upvote twice I'd do it again for the time you spent.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lefteqn{
\lim_{\bigtriangleup t \to 0^+}\int_{\bigtriangleup t}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\varphi(t_1-\bigtriangleup t,x)-\varphi(t_1,x)}{(-\bigtriangleup t)} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 
}\\
&=&\lim_{\bigtriangleup t \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\varphi(t_1-\bigtriangleup t,x)-\varphi(t_1,x)}{(-\bigtriangleup t)} \chi_{(\bigtriangleup t,T)}(t_1) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 
\\
&= &\int_{0}^{T} \! \int_{\Omega} \! D(t_1,x) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t_1} (t_1,x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t_1 .
\end{eqnarray*}
```

But you'd rather write `\Delta` instead of `\bigtriangleup`.

Comment: `eqnarray`! Run for your lives!

Comment: @Jubobs I do know `eqnarray`'s limitations. But I also know, how to adjust this environment.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thank you, this is looking well. Is there a rule of how to line-break equations and math expressions? For example would it be considered wrong if I separated each line by $$ and then it would be all centred?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Really, never ever use `eqnarray`.

Comment: @vessel Sugested `eqnarray` is the simplest one, making 3 columns. If you need more sophisticated breaking, please consider using of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @egreg So I am quickly leading vessel to the `amsmath` package.:-)